# How do I build a nested linked list using recursion?

Tags: java, list, recursion, linked-list, nested

So in class we are asked to read in a text file. The format is like such:

a b ( c d ( e f ) g ) h

We need to build a nested linked list like such:

a

b

.....c

.....d

..........e

..........f

.....g

h

Each left parenthesis denotes moving down a level, then a right parenthesis denote moving back up one level.
So, a links to b, b has a nested link to c, c links to d, d has a nested link to e, e links to f, d links to g, then b links to h

We are using a modified LLNode:

public class LLNode 
{

```
protected LLNode<T> link;
protected LLNode<T> nested;
protected T info;
public LLNode(T info) 
{
    this.info = info;
    link = null;
    nested = null;
}
public void setInfo(T info) 
{
    this.info = info;
}
public T getInfo() 
{
    return info;
}
public void setLink(LLNode<T> link) 
{
    this.link = link;
}
public LLNode<T> getLink() 
{
    return link;
}
public void setNested(LLNode<T> nested)
{
    this.nested = nested;
}
public LLNode<T> getNested()
{
    return nested;
}
```

}

We need to use recursion to read the input file, create nodes for each letter and link them accordingly. I have no clue on how to approach this recursively. Any help at all is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please see: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Answer (score 0):

I know I shouldn't give you the answers to your homework but I like recursion so I couldn't resist this. Please spend some time understanding and possibly modifying the code, before you hand it in. Clever teachers search through StackOverflow, especially if the stuff you hand in is surprisingly good :)

I had to add a `parent` to the LLNode. Instead of the parent attribute, you could have a list of LLNode in the NodeParser class, where the list keeps track of the most recent father, grandfather, etc.

The new LLNode:

```
public class LLNode<T> {

    protected LLNode<T> link;
    protected LLNode<T> nested;
    protected LLNode<T> parent; // New field
    protected T info;

    public LLNode(T info) {
        <old code>
        parent = null;
    }

    <old code>

    public void setParent(LLNode<T> parent) {
        this.parent = parent;
    }

    public LLNode<T> getParent() {
        return parent;
    }

}
```

And then the parser (including a recursive printer!):

```
public class NodeParser {

private String str;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new NodeParser();
}

public NodeParser() {
    this.str = "a b ( c d ( e f ) g ) h ( i j ( k ) l ) m n";
    LLNode<Character> topNode = new LLNode<>(null);
    parse(topNode, false);
    print("", topNode.getLink());
}

private synchronized void parse(LLNode<Character> node, boolean nested) {
    if (str.length() == 0) {
        return;
    }
    while (str.charAt(0) == ' ') {
        str = str.substring(1);
    }
    char c = str.charAt(0);
    str = str.substring(1);

    if (c == '(') {
        parse(node, true);
    } else if (c == ')') {
        parse(node.getParent(), false);
    } else if (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z') {
        LLNode<Character> nextNode = new LLNode<>(c);
        if (nested) {
            node.setNested(nextNode);
            nextNode.setParent(node);
        } else {
            node.setLink(nextNode);
            nextNode.setParent(node.getParent());
        }
        parse(nextNode, false);
    }
}

private void print(String indent, LLNode<Character> node) {
    if (node == null) {
        return;
    }
    System.out.println(indent + node.getInfo());
    print(indent + "  ", node.getNested());
    print(indent, node.getLink());
}

}
```